# Docker set --log-opt on running container

Tags: logging, docker

I am running into a little problem with my Docker logs on a critical piece of infrastructure. Apparently we started the container without the `--log-opt max-size` setting so the logs now grow at a pretty alarming rate. I would like to avoid having to restart the service but need to limit the amount of logfiles docker is writing to disk.

Is there a way to set the max log size without restarting the container?

We are running `docker 1.10.3-0~trusty` on `Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *logrotate*. It is installed by default on Ubuntu servers and you can check `/etc/logrotate.d/` for existing logrotate policies.

Following is an example policy to rotate log files daily. You can copy-paste this to `/etc/logrotate.d/docker-logs`

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log {
  daily
  rotate 7
  compress
  missingok
  copytruncate
}
```

You can read more about logrotate [here](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)

Comment: Wow I did not know you can do wildcard signatures for logrotate. I was worried that having different container ids would screw up my logrotate config on restarting/starting new containers. Awesome thank you very much!!